# Python Tkinter: How to disable window showing in taskbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am coding an app displays an label on the screen. I want it to be invisible in the taskbar. It is for Windows 7. I am using Python 3.8.1

Code:

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk as itk
import time
from threading import Thread
import random

root = Tk()
width = 400
height = 400

lbl_deneme = Label(root, text = 'Test')
#lbl_deneme.place(x = 25, y = 25, anchor = 'center')
lbl_deneme.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

root.attributes('-transparentcolor', root['bg'])
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.title('Başlık')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @stovfl I do not want to hide window. I want to hide it in the taskbar.

Comment: It's Window Manager dependent, try different [`-type`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M19), `utility` will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the code to do that. I learned that I only need to disable Windows default frame.

Code:

```py
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

Comment: do you know how to revert?

Answer (score 0):

Try its :

```
root.wm_attributes("-toolwindow", True)
```

*A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the dialog that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB. If a tool window has a system menu, its icon is not displayed on the title bar.*

Doc: [Tcl/Tk -toolwindow](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.html#M10)

[WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles#ws_ex_toolwindow)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).